# Show that $|A+A| < 2.5 |A| $ with $A = \{ [n \sqrt{2}] : 1 \leq n \leq N \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, additive-combinatorics

Let $A = \{ [n \sqrt{2}] : 1 \leq n \leq N  \}$ then can we estimate the size of the [sumset](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/additive_combinatorics.pdf) $A+A$ ?

$$ A+A = \big\{ [m \sqrt{2}] + [n \sqrt{2}] : 1 \leq m \leq N, 1 \leq n \leq N \big\} $$

Here are two possibilities:

$$ |A| \leq | A + A| \leq \binom{|A|}{2} $$

Can we do any better for the size of $A+A$?  I know that if $|A+A| = |A|$ then $A$ is the [coset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset) of a finite group.   For example, do we have that

$$|A+A| < 2.5 |A| $$

for sufficiently large $N$ ?

---

Computer models suggest $\sigma(A) = |A+A|/|A| \approx 2 \sqrt{2}$ as $N \to \infty$ but also $\sigma(A) > 2\sqrt{2} - \epsilon$ for e.g. $\epsilon > 0.1$

For $N = 2500$ we have that $|A+A| \approx (2.827)|A|$.  And maybe in general it's always close to twice the spacing.  At least, for the type of sequence I have written down.

In fact, I think we've argued in the comments that $|A+A| < 3|A|$ and certainly that ratio is $>1$.  That's could be sufficient for many argments.

---

I wonder if the answer to this problem changes if I replace integer part $[\cdot ]$ with round up, or nearest integer function.

Comment: We have a trivial estimate $|A+A|\geq 2|A|-1$ for any $A$, so the answer to the last question is "no". I believe we do have an inequality of the sort $|A+A|<3|A|$ in this particular case.

Comment: Note that any element of $A+A$ is an integer between $2$ and $2\sqrt{2}N$, so $|A+A|\leq 2\sqrt{2}|A|$.

Comment: @wojowu fixed. Can we improve upper bound of $2\sqrt{2}\approx 2.82$ ?

Comment: Just some initial investigation:let $a_n = \lfloor n \sqrt{2} \rfloor$

Then note that either 

$$a_n + a_m = a_{n+m}$$

or

$$a_n + a_m + 1 = a_{n+m}$$

Numbers not of the form $a_n$ are of the form $b_n = a_n + 2n$ (look up beatty sequence, https://oeis.org/A001951 and https://oeis.org/A001952). It is always true that $b_n +1$ is some $a_k$.

Comment: @Aryabhata i guess here that's as close as we'll get to "solving" it. this could have applications to quasicrystals such as [Penrose tilings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling).

Comment: @cactus314: Interesting! btw, another thing that might be relevant is the Schnirelmann density related theorems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnirelmann_density (just a thought, haven't tried anything myself).

Comment: By brute force, we have $|A+A| = 2\lfloor\sqrt{2}N\rfloor - \epsilon_n$ where $\epsilon \in \{ 1, 2 \}$ for $N \le 40000$ and $\epsilon_n = 2$ with a probability $\sim \sqrt{2}-1$.

Comment: @achillehui perhaps one could study the set $\{  n : \epsilon_n = |A+A| - 2 \lfloor \sqrt{2} N \rfloor \rfloor \} = 1 \}$ which looks pretty [random](https://www.random.org/)